# How do I fix `no_running_cluster_nodes` when clustering RabbitMQ?

Tags: debian, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I'm trying to cluster two RabbitMQs.

I have two machines (rabbit1 & rabbit2) with Debian Wheezy running `rabbitmq-server 2.8.4-1`. (I know that's old, but that's what comes with Debian Wheezy.)

On rabbit1 I run...

```
# rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping node rabbit@rabbit1 ...
...done.
# rabbitmqctl reset
Resetting node rabbit@rabbit1 ...
...done.
# rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@rabbit2
Clustering node rabbit@rabbit1 with [rabbit@rabbit2] ...
Error: {no_running_cluster_nodes,[rabbit@rabbit2],[rabbit@rabbit2]}
```

But I don't get past this error. What am I missing?

Things I checked:

- I'm using the same cookie in /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie on both machines.
- I added entries to `/etc/hosts` and can ping each machine from the other (using only rabbit1, resp. rabbit2 as a name).
- Iptables are empty.

**Update:**

From rabbit1 I verfied with nmap that epmd on rabbit2 is listening on 4369.

```
root@rabbit1:~# nmap -p 1- rabbit2
...
PORT      STATE SERVICE
4369/tcp  open  epmd
5672/tcp  open  amqp
51629/tcp open  unknown
```

**Solution: (Cheating)**

It was neither the erlang cookie, nor the hostnames, nor the firewall. Actually I still don't know what it was. But I finally upgraded to RabbitMQ 3.5.4 by installing the Debian package provided by RabbitMQ. (I know this is cheating.) After the upgrade everything worked as expected with no further changes to my setup.

Comment: Show me the output of `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` on `rabbit2`.  Maybe `rabbit2` doesn't know that its called `rabbit2`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, turned out to be my `.erlang.cookie` even though I was sure I'd set them to the same value on both machines (always good to double check).

It's possible that another `.erlang.cookie` is being used, depending on how rabbitmq is started. If it's been started with the init script, then `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` should be correct. If you started rabbitmq like this, `rabbitmq-server -detached`, then it may be in the user's home directory.

You can check the cookie hash rabbitmqctl is using (will be the same as rabbitmq-server if it can connect when you don't supply a `-n` flag) by running `rabbitmqctl -n notarealnode status` which will print out diagnostics.

Hostnames can also be tricky, as both the local node and the remote node need to identify each other and themselves with the same names. In other words, `rabbit1`'s

Also, you didn't mention where you're running this, but mine are in an EC2 VPC which means I had to set the Security Group to allow traffic between the nodes. If you're not in EC2, then maybe there is some other sort of external firewall that needs configuration.